# Replace two (//) with just one (/) in a path using Regex in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I've combined two paths together however, I need to replace the double slashes in the whole path with just one.

```
$path1 = 'C:\NewFolder\'
$path2 = '\Samplefolder\files'
$final = $path1 + $path2
```

The result comes out as: `C:\NewFolder\\Samplefolder\files`, making it an invalid path. I want to replace these two slashes with just one and need it so that wherever there are two `\\` in the path, they are replaced with just one `\`.

I have tried doing

```
$final = [regex]::replace($final,"\\\\","\\")
```

and

```
$final = $final.replace('\\\\+', '\\')
```

but it's not working.

Comment: The `.replace` in `$final.replace('\\\\+', '\\')` is a string replacement method that does not accept regex. Just use ``$final.replace('\\','\')``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that but the result is still `C:\NewFolder\\Samplefolder\files`

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/xmwXlRc

Comment: use `$final -replace '\\\\','\'` or `join-path $path1 $path2` and forget string manipulation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way of joining paths in PowerShell is to use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$path1 = 'C:\NewFolder\'
$path2 = '\Samplefolder\files'
$final = Join-Path $path1 $path2
```

PowerShell's `-replace` operator uses regex matching. You must backslash escape the special `\` character.

```
$path1 = 'C:\NewFolder\'
$path2 = '\Samplefolder\files'
$final = $path1 + $path2 -replace '\\\\','\'
```

You can opt for the String class `Replace()` method, which does literal string and character searches.

```
$path1 = 'C:\NewFolder\'
$path2 = '\Samplefolder\files'
$final = ($path1 + $path2).Replace('\\','\')
```